# PHP problems with retrieving names from multiple links using $_GET

Tags: php, hyperlink, get

Ok, so I'm having trouble using $_GET. It seems like when I try to use it with multiple links, it comes out null. The first part of the code is just producing two links and then figuring out which link was clicked. The second part is creating a bunch of links with people's names. The problem is that my $num variable always comes out to be null. The weird thing is that I tried not using $_GET for the first part, I only used it for the second part, and $num was no longer null. However, some other stuff didn't work the way I want it to so I have to do it this way. The two pieces of code are in different functions. Is there something about $_GET that won't let me do this? Thanks in advance!

This is the first part of the code:

```
$profLink = "<br><a href=?urlID=sortProf >By Professor</a></br>";
$yearLink = "<br><a href=?urlID=sortYear >By Year</a></br>";

echo $profLink;
echo $yearLink;

 if(isset($_GET['urlID'])){
    $urlID = $_GET['urlID'];}

if ($urlID == "sortProf"){

$v = sortByLastName($v);

 displayNames($v, $k);

}

else if ($urlID == "sortYear"){
echo "check2";


}
}
```

This is the second part (where the trouble is):

```
foreach($v as $name){
        $nameLink = "<a href=?num=$nameCount > $name </a><br />";
        echo $nameLink;
        $nameCount++;
       // echo $nameCount;
    }
     if(isset($_GET['num'])){
    $num = $_GET['num'];}
```

Comment: the href should use quotes

Comment: You should try writing valid html: `<a href='?num=$namecount' ...`. attributes MUST be quoted in html these days.

Comment: _“attributes MUST be quoted in html these days”_ – not true. “These days” can only mean HTML5, and in that there are [defined conditions under which an attribute value may be noted unquoted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#unquoted). (That aside, it is of course good advice to _always_ quote attribute values.)

Comment: How would that be valid in PHP? If I just put in the quotes there it won't run.

Comment: @MarcB With HTML5 quotes are no longer needed with attributes, though I prefer to still use them myself.  Here's the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes).

Comment: I got beat in the time it took to look up the reference...nice one, @CBroe

Comment: _“How would that be valid in PHP? If I just put in the quotes there it won't run.”_ – go learn some _basics_, please. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I've had to teach myself all of this, so I'm sorry if I don't know everything yet. All I asked was a simple question. I'm just looking for some guidance on how this would be formatted because I've tried several different ways but with no success.

Comment: You can escape quotes inside a string with `\"` instead of just `"`. You must add quotes to your href, because of the =